# is the formula for negative compound interest the same as normal?

Tags: php, math, formula

I have a calculator that works out the future house prices based on the rate of inflation. Currently my inflation rate runs from 1% to 8%. I want to be able to make it go from -2% to 8%.

Would your standard compound interest calculator work correctly for negative interest rates too or would I have to make some alterations?

Thanks in advance

```
$inflation_house = $house_price_inflation_rate;
$drawdown_y = $years_of_inflation;
$ppp = 0; $rrr = 0; 
$qqq = 1; $ttt = 0; 
$ppp = $currenthouse; 
$rrr = $inflation_house; 
$ttt = $drawdown_y;
$rrr = (( $rrr / 100 ) / $qqq); 
$fvvv = $ppp * pow( ( 1 + $rrr ), $ttt); 
$AAA = $ppp * pow( ( 1 + $rrr ), $ttt) -$ppp;
```

Comment: $ppp = 0;

    $rrr = 0;

    $qqq = 1;

    $ttt = 0;

    $rttt = 0;

    $AAA = 0;


    $ppp = $currenthouse;

    $rrr = $inflation_house;

    $rttt = $inflation_house;

    $ttt = $drawdown_y;




    $rrr = (( $rrr / 100 ) / $qqq);

    $rttt = (( $rttt / 100 ) / $qqq);


    $fvvv = $ppp * pow( ( 1 + $rrr ), $ttt);



    $AAA  = $ppp * pow( ( 1 + $rrr ), $ttt) -$ppp;

Comment: Shouldn't high school math be a prerequisite for working an a compound interest calculator?

Answer (score 4):

The formula is n × (1 + growth rate)<sup>p</sup>. This works because you're basically doing (for an growth of 1% over 2 periods) n × 1.01 × 1.01 = n × 101% × 101%. This also works for negative growth: then it's just n × 0.98 x 0.98, (2% deflation) for example. The growth rate just becomes negative.